# wxPython not responding

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, wxpython

I'm new to python and now I want to try wxpython, but I can't continue even at the very beginning.
Following the toturial,

```
import wx
app = wx.App(False)  
frame = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "Hello World") 
frame.Show(True)
```

after I did that, the new windows stops responding as soon as the it appears or I try to click it. Then I can only force close it and the editor restarts.
All the same on shell or IDLE, even all the same on different computers(I happened to bought a new one). Maybe I've done something wrong since I searched the internet and it seems no one encounters the problem, but I can't figure it out.

I'm using the latest python(x,y).
In addition, I tried tkinter also on my old computer and the problem is the same, if I remember rightly.

Comment: wxPython, tkinter etc. usually do not play nicely with IDLE. Try starting the code from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

that's because the app loop is not running. usually, you also have to do:

```
app.MainLoop()
```

after frame.Show(). of course, now your console will be running the main loop, and you won't get your console back until after the app exits (well, when your main window closes), which probably isn't what you want either.

i haven't used python(x,y), but from a quick look, it looks like it supports IPython(x,y). If you use that as the console, then you can do

```
%gui wx
```

after loading, and then instead of creating/running the app yourself, IPython itself implements the app and does event processing in a special way as an *input hook* - which means that while it is waiting for you to type something, instead of just waiting, it actively polls the gui to see if there are active events and processes them if they are. This can create some interesting problems as well, but then you can just create the window & show it, and it will work correctly....